# Run a series of commands for every file in a directory

Tags: windows, command-line

To add subtitles to a single file I use the following command:

`mkvmerge.exe -o g:\movie01.mkv --default-track 0 --language 0:pl movie01.mkv movie01.srt`

**Where:**

`movie01.mkv` is the name of a video file

`movie01.srt` is the name of a subtitle file (it is always the same as the video file)

`g:\movie01.mkv` is the output file

**How do I run the above-mentioned command for every file in a directory?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will loop through all mkv files and run the command for each of them (I suggest putting it in a `.bat` file). The command should be run in the directory that contains your mkv-files.

```
for %%A in (*.mkv) do if /i "%%~XA"==".mkv" ( 
    c:\<path to mkvmerge>\mkvmerge.exe -o g:\"%%A" --default-track 0 --language 0:pl "%%A" "%%~nA.srt"
)
```

`%%A` is equal to the exact filename.

`%%~nA` is equal to the filename without filetype.

Comment: `mkvtoonix` gives me an error: `Error: No source files were given.`

Comment: Are you running the command in the directory with your mkv files? (try placing the .bat file in that dir and run it.

Comment: Yes, I am. The problem was `""`. When deleted everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Provided all files have the .mkv extension, how about this:

```
for /r %%video in (*.mkv) do mkvmerge.exe -o %%video --default-track 0 --language 0:pl %%video.srt
```

`%%video`is the variable which identifies each files in the current folder with the specified extension. After `do` I run the command on each file, and I use the same variable to call the srt file.

Comment: `mkvtoonix` gives me an error: `Error: No source files were given.`